# Deploy Custom Action to SharePoint 2019 list using SPFx extension

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-2019, spfx-extension

I have a requirement to use SPFx and provide a custom action button in a list in SharePoint classic site. This button should be available in the ribbon work in both the SharePoint modern site and classic sites too.

I have to use SPFx for the development of this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to use SPFX Extension on classic site. If the requirement is to have an action in both, modern and classi, you have to create two separate "applications".

- [Build your first ListView Command Set extension (SPFX)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)
- [Add and Modify User Custom Actions Using JavaScript (classic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185004(v%3Doffice.14))